# Разработка базы данных для склада

Tags: база-данных

Необходимо реализовать базу данных для выдачи спецодежды. 
Есть сущность  Спецодежда:

- Код СИЗ
- Наименование СИЗ
- Сезон
- Код размера
- Срок носки (в месяцах)
- Количество

Как лучше распределить сущности? Стоит ли размер выносить отдельной таблицей?

Comment: Какие сущности и куда вы пытаетесь распределять? В вопросе у вас только одна сущность. Выносить размер в отдельную таблицу - скорее да, чем нет.

Comment: Код размера
Рост
Размер одежды
Размер обуви
Размер головного убора